# Quickest, most ghetto way to bring up "webserver" which outputs results of command

Tags: webserver

I need a "webserver" that can run a specific, hard-coded bash command and output the results.  That's it.  I don't need to look at the request, don't even care if it IS a request, don't care about the URL, etc.  It doesn't need to be particularly reliable, and can monopolize port 80.  I guess the key point here is I'm pretty sure I don't need an actual web server.

I know the normal way to do something like this is set up a proper webserver, with server-side HTML generation functionality, etc., etc.

I'm hoping that there's a faster way to do this, possibly involving a single bash command.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Netcat's probably what you're after. Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16640054/minimal-web-server-using-netcat

Comment: The "Programming Perl" book has an example Perl script to listen to a socket and Do A Thing. Also see `netcat`.

Comment: Thanks, both.  Happy to delete the question if it's considered a duplicate or "just google it" thing.  I couldn't quite figure out what to google was my issue.